# copy the next cell down and paste on the same cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using below code to just copy the next cell down and paste on the same cell everytime.

Let me explain it. For Example Sheet1 has for values or more in the `Range("L1:L" & lastrow)` i will run the code if range("E4") isempty then L1 value will be updated in E4

then again run the code now L2 value will be updated in E4.
then again run the code now L3 value will be updated in E4.
then again run the code now L4 value will be updated in E4.
and so on.

If L4 has last value then exit sub as below code is working.

is there any easiest way to do this. Looking forward to your help.

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Set sht1 = Sheet1

Dim r As Range
Set r = Range(sht1.Cells(1, 12), sht1.Cells(1, 12).End(xlDown))

Dim offset_row As Variant

If IsEmpty(sht1.Cells(4, 5).Value) Then
  offset_row = 0
Else
  offset_row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(sht1.Cells(4, 5).Value, r, 0)
End If

If Not IsError(offset_row) Then
  If offset_row <> r.Rows.Count Then
    sht1.Cells(1, 12).Offset(offset_row, 0).copy Destination:=sht1.Cells(4, 5)
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Not clear what you want accomplishing. Do you want running your code many times and each time to make it return the next value from column L:L in the same "E4" cel? If not, and the process it is done on the same run, you will have in "E4" **the last value of L:L column**. Is this what you want doing, in that complicated way? Please, better clarify what you want accomplishing. **In words**.

Comment: Yes when i run the code each time it should paste next cell value to E4 @FaneDuru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Write Next Cell Value

- Note that `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` or `WorksheetFunction.Match` is the same and if the value is not found, an error will occur i.e. your testing for an error value has no effect (not gonna happen). It should be handled with `On Error`.
- On the other hand, `Application.Match` will result in either a number or an error value and can be tested with `IsError` or `IsNumeric`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub writeNextCellValue()
    
    Const dCellAddress As String = "E4"
    Const sFirstCellAddress As String = "L1"
    
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Column Range
    Dim dCell As Range ' Destination Cell Range
    Dim isSourceColumnRangeValid As Boolean ' Source Column Range Validator
    
    With Sheet1.Range(sFirstCellAddress)
        Set srg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If Not srg Is Nothing Then
            Set srg = .Resize(srg.Row - .Row + 1)
            isSourceColumnRangeValid = True
            Set dCell = .Worksheet.Range(dCellAddress)
        End If
    End With
    
    If isSourceColumnRangeValid Then
        If dCell.Value = "" Then ' Value is "".
            dCell.Value = srg.Cells(1).Value
        Else ' Value is not "".
            Dim cIndex As Variant
            cIndex = Application.Match(dCell.Value, srg, 0)
            If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then ' Value found.
                If cIndex = srg.Rows.Count Then ' Last value found.
                    'dCell.Value = ""
                    'dCell.Value = srg.Cells(1).Value
                Else ' Not last value found.
                    dCell.Value = srg.Cells(cIndex + 1)
                End If
            Else ' Value not found.
                'dCell.Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @VBasic2008 its working as per expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the next code:

```
Sub FillNextCellVal()
 Dim sht1 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range
 Dim ECell As Range, cExist As Range, i As Long
 
 Set sht1 = Sheet1
 Set ECell = sht1.Range("E4")
 lastR = sht1.Range("L" & sht1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng = sht1.Range("L1:L" & lastR)
 
 If ECell.value = "" Then
    ECell.value = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas(1).value
 Else
    Set cExist = rng.Find(What:=ECell.value, After:=rng.cells(1), _
              LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
    If Not cExist Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To lastR - cExist.row
            If cExist.Offset(i).value <> "" Then
                ECell.value = cExist.Offset(i).value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it goes to the last value it should go for the first if cell is empty then go for 2nd then 3rd then 4th i have updated a gif. Please see.

Comment: @Mento: I could see only the condition for "E4" to not be empty... Please, test the updated code which returns first cell which is not empty. Without iteration...

Comment: Yes it returns first cell but does not return to second one after running the code again. @FaneDuru

Comment: @Mento: I am afraid I couldn't understand what you want accomplishing. Maybe because I could not imagine why would you need such a way... Please, test the updated code. Even if you accepted an answer...

Comment: @Mento: Can you tell me what program did you use to create the animated gif you posted? I have Macro Recorder, but it saves with its own extension. If you, also used it, how could you convert it in a gif file? Thanks! Do you use ReaConverter?

Comment: Yes Thank you now the code is perfect. whenever the value will be updated in that  E4 my other code will run that was the purpose of this code.

Comment: I just write on google video converter to GIF online. I opened 2 to 3 websites and one of them converted this to GIF. I recorded the the video from my machine then converted this to gif.

Comment: @Mento: Thanks! Did you use Macro Recorder (Bartels Media GmbH?), or a different application? I found some sites telling that thy can convert from rtf to jpg (or any video format, because it is easy to convert from mp4, for instance, to gif animated), but they refused the file record with the above mentioned application...

Comment: No i never used mentioned application and i didn't converted files other than MP4 to gif. So i don't know about that much.